# No detecta mis variables de WTForms en visual code

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo este problema, algo cambié o se actualizo algo que ahora no detecta mis variables de mi formulario generado en Flask Form, todo funcionaba pero actualmente dejó de detectar las variables de mi formulario como en este ejemplo form.nombres.data deberian tener otro color desde nombre.data que es la variable del formulario

Adjunto imagen para que puedan tener más clara la idea, de funcionar el codigo funciona pero, la detección de las variables ayuda a identificar posibles errores de escribir mal alguna de ellas y uno ya puede corregir, ahora no lo hace y es como ir a ciegas, no se si se desactivo algo en mi visual code o cambie algo, o hay una nueva versión de algo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mencionas que adjuntas una imagen, que en realidad no adjuntas. [Edit] tu pregunta para agregar lo que haga falta. Por favor no publiques imágenes de código, sino el texto del código como tal. Por otro lado, no entiendo bien a qué te refieres con que no _detecta_ las variables. ¿quién no detecta? ¿Tienes un error al ejecutar tu script? o ¿por qué usas la etiqueta Python?, quizás no tengas que usarla. Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: #DATOS
@app.route('/documento_template',methods=['GET','POST'])
def datos_personales():
    
    form=clase.Formulario()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        valor1=form.nombres.data    
        valor2=form.cargo.data
        valor3=form.direccion.data
        
        datos=(valor1,valor2.upper(),valor3)
        adm.registrar.informacion(datos)

    return render_template('documento_template.html',form=form)

Comment: agregue la imagen para que se entienda mejor la pregunta, lo que esta subrayado son las variables que no detecta Visual Code

Comment: Una cosa es visual studio y otra cosa es el intérprete de python. El resaltados de sintaxis de vscode puede fallar, pero si no tienes problemas al ejecutar el código entonces el problema solo es de vscode

Comment: bueno el código funciona normal, gracias por la información, sino que si es de ayuda lo otro para identificar errores